# Get string constants for punctuation characters in Python

Tags: python, string, punctuation

How can I access Python's string constants ?

I need to get a list of punctuation marks which Python docs say are in [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation)

This won't work

```
''.punctuation
''.get_value("punctuation")
```

Is what I'm trying even possible?

Comment: @PrincessOftheUniverse You're -1 this because of a bad title? Why not just edit it then.

Comment: I am so happy to have found this question. Made it more accessible by editing the title and tags (incl. [recommended letter-case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252624/title-case-or-sentence-case)) and inserted the missing link where the docs said `string.punctuation`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`string` in `string.punctuation` isn't referring to type `str`, but to a [string module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

```
In [32]: import string

In [33]: string.punctuation
Out[33]: '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
>>> import string
>>> string
<module 'string' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/string.pyc'>
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

Answer (score 0):

These are variables in the module so you do not need an instance use the module name. Note for others I assume the python docs referred to in the question are [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)
e.g.

```
import string
print(string.punctuation)
```

gives

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```