# How Do You Remove Punctuation From A String? (Python)

Tags: python, string, loops

I need some more help. Basically, I'm trying to return the user input with all non-space and non-alphanumeric characters removed. I made code for this much of the way, but I keep getting errors...

```
def remove_punctuation(s):
    '''(str) -> str
    Return s with all non-space or non-alphanumeric  
    characters removed. 
    >>> remove_punctuation('a, b, c, 3!!')
    'a b c 3'
    '''   
    punctuation = '''''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''  
    my_str =  s 
    no_punct = ""  
    for char in my_str:  
        if char not in punctuation:  
            no_punct = no_punct + char  
    return(no_punct)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please describe or post the errors. No one can help you otherwise

Comment: What's going on with all those quotation marks?  Try something more like `'!()-[]{};:\'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'`

Comment: "Python Shell, prompt 2, line 1
Syntax Error: invalid syntax: <string>, line 1, pos 31" is my specific error.

Comment: Is the code you have here the first thing in the file you're running?

Comment: This code is the first thing in the file, yes.

Comment: Note there is a constant [`string.punctuation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15584430/1270789) that contains all these characters.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's will work for you !

```
def remove_punctuation(s):
    new_s = [i for i in s if i.isalnum() or i.isalpha() or i.isspace()]
    return ''.join(new_s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but when I try to evaluate it, this happens:

>>> remove_punctuation( "Hello I must be going.!")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 2, line 1
  File "C:/Users/Marquela Nunes/Desktop/Test Python.py", line 8, in <module>
    new_s = [i for i in s if i.isalnum() or i.isalpha()]
builtins.NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: This also removes the spaces

Comment: @MarquelaNunes you should get a param when you call `remove_punctuation` like this remove_punctuation('hello ,asdns')

Comment: @James I am no catch this (ignore spaces)

Comment: Sorry! I made an error on my end. This worked! but can i ask what you did to remove the spaces? (I'm really new to python)

Comment: @MarquelaNunes I have already update the code, you can keep your space alive ~~

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @MarquelaNunes That's good doc for you http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the regular expression module? If so, you can do:

```
import re

def remove_punctuation(s)
    return re.sub(r'[^\w 0-9]|_', '', s)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use the regular expression module in this assignment but I'll keep in mind just in case!

Answer (score 0):

> There is an inbuilt function to get the punctuations...

```
    s="This is a String with Punctuations !!!!@@$##%"
    import string
    punctuations = set(string.punctuations)
    withot_punctuations = ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch not in punctuations)
```

You will get the string without punctuations

```
output:
This is a String with Punctuations
```

[You can find more about string functions here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)

Answer (score 0):

I added the space character to your punctuation string and cleanup up your use of quotes in the punctuation string. Then I cleaned up the code in my own style so that can see the small differences.

```
def remove_punctuation(str):
    '''(str) -> str
    Return s with all non-space or non-alphanumeric
    characters removed.
    >>> remove_punctuation('a, b, c, 3!!')
    'a b c 3'
    '''
    punctuation = "! ()-[]{};:'\"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~"
    no_punct = ""
    for c in str:
        if c not in punctuation:
            no_punct += c
    return(no_punct)

result = remove_punctuation('a, b, c, 3!!')
print("Result 1: ", result)
result = remove_punctuation("! ()-[]{};:'\"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~")
print("Result 2: ", result)
```